# ODBC Data Source Connection Successful but TNS Unresolved in VBScript

Tags: oracle, vbscript, odbc, tnsnames, tns

I am trying to make a connection to Oracle DB from VBScript.  I've added all the environment variables and the code can locate the file of TNSNAMES.ora but cannot resolve the connection.

When I test the connectivity from the ODBC Data Source Administrator, I get a 'Success' result, but I still cannot access this from the code.

```
con.ConnectionString = "DSN=DATA;Uid=wh;Pwd=pwd;"
con.Open    'This is where it fails
```

I have tried many connection strings but all fail

```
OracleConnString = "Driver={Oracle in instantclient_18_3};server=server;database=db;trusted_connection=Yes;"

DB_CONN_STRING = "Driver={Oracle in instantclient_18_3}; " & _
    "(DESCRIPTION=" & _
    "(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host)(PORT = port)" & _
    "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=srv_name)))"

CONN_STRING = "CONNECT wh/pwd@//host/db"
```

How can I connect to the database from the script?

[image: ODBC Success]

[image: ODBC Admin]

[image: Error]

Comment: Could you please check IP or host is are correct in the tnsnames.ora file.

Comment: @KajalKundu yes, in my tnsnames.ora, the host is correct and comes back with a 'Success'

Comment: See documentation of the specific ORA-12154 error -- on [orafaq](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-12154) and [ora-code](https://web.archive.org/web/20180828083233/http://ora-12154.ora-code.com/). (Also note that ODBC ConnectionString keywords are case-sensitive, so `con.ConnectionString = "DSN=DATA;Uid=wh;Pwd=pwd;"` should be `con.ConnectionString = "DSN=DATA;UID=wh;PWD=pwd;"`.)

Comment: @TallTed  on another user's machine, the same connection string is applied and works with lowercase.  I'm sure it's a problem with Environment Variables configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mix several topics.

You hide the DSN name and the "Data Source Name", this makes it impossible for use to provide you the correct connection string.

If you like to use the ODBC DSN then the connection string must be

```
DSN=▇▇▇▇DATA;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword
```

However, you must create a **System** DSN, not a **User** DSN (see [ODBC DSN](http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=89#DSN)). However, typically you don't use the ODBC DSN because you have to create the DSN on the target machine which is additional configuration work.

Connection string without DSN would be

```
Driver={Oracle in instantclient_18_3};Dbq=?????;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
or
Driver={Oracle in instantclient_18_3};Server=?????;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

see https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-in-oraclient11g_home1/

If you use full DB name like `(DESCRIPTION=...` then you don't need any `tnsnames.ora` file. The purpose of this file is to resolve an alias to this full DB name.

Ensure that the ODBC driver is the same architecture, i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit as your VBS environment.

Either use `%windir%\system32\odbcad32.exe` + `%windir%\system32\cscript.exe`

or `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` + `%windir%\SysWOW64\cscript.exe`